# TextViews in dialog box don't display on Android 2.3 and below

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a collection of objects with information that can be displayed in a dialog box when the object is selected by the user. The layout for my dialog is as follows:

```
<ScrollView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:scrollbars="vertical"
>

<TableLayout
    android:id="@+id/overlay_item_dialog_table"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:paddingLeft="10sp"
    android:paddingRight="10sp"
    >

    <TableRow   android:id="@+id/overlay_item_dialog_object_id_row"
                android:visibility="gone">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/overlay_item_dialog_object_id_label"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/overlay_label_object_id" 
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:layout_gravity="right"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/overlay_item_dialog_object_id"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:paddingLeft="10sp"
            android:layout_gravity="left"/>
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow   android:id="@+id/overlay_item_dialog_latitude_row"
                android:visibility="gone">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:text="@string/label_latitude" 
            android:layout_gravity="right"
        />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/overlay_item_dialog_latitude"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:paddingLeft="10sp"
            android:layout_gravity="left"/>
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow   android:id="@+id/overlay_item_dialog_longitude_row"
                android:visibility="gone">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:text="@string/label_longitude"
            android:layout_gravity="right" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/overlay_item_dialog_longitude"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:paddingLeft="10sp"
            android:layout_gravity="left"/>
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow   android:id="@+id/overlay_item_dialog_date_row"
                android:visibility="gone">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:text="@string/label_date"
            android:layout_gravity="right" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/overlay_item_dialog_date"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:paddingLeft="10sp"
            android:layout_gravity="left"/>
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow   android:id="@+id/overlay_item_dialog_time_row"
                android:visibility="gone">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:text="@string/label_time"
            android:layout_gravity="right" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/overlay_item_dialog_time"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:paddingLeft="10sp"
            android:layout_gravity="left"/>
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow   android:id="@+id/overlay_item_dialog_direction_row"
                android:visibility="gone">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/label_direction" 
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:layout_gravity="right"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/overlay_item_dialog_direction"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:paddingLeft="10sp"
            android:layout_gravity="left"/>
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow   android:id="@+id/overlay_item_dialog_speed_row"
                android:visibility="gone">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/label_speed" 
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:layout_gravity="right"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/overlay_item_dialog_speed"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:paddingLeft="10sp"
            android:layout_gravity="left"/>
    </TableRow>

</TableLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

The dialog box itself is a android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment. For each row in the layout where the visibility is set to "gone", these are optional fields, and I do something like the following to make them visible when necessary (this is used in my onCreateDialog method):

```
if ( position.hasSpeed() )
{
        ( (TableRow) rootView.findViewById( R.id.overlay_item_dialog_speed_row ) ).setVisibility( View.VISIBLE );
        ( (TextView) rootView.findViewById( R.id.overlay_item_dialog_speed ) ).setText( position.getSpeedString() );
}
```

These are parameters that are quite common, but optional, and I want to to appear before everything else, hence why they are handled this way.

Other parameters are handled as follows, where "layout" is a the TableLayout named "overlay_item_dialog_table", and was taken from the root view obtained by calling getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate( R.layout.overlay_item_dialog, null )

```
for ( PositionParameter param : position.getPositionParameters().values() )
    {
        if ( param.getValue() != null && param.getValue().trim().length() != 0 )
        {
            TableRow tableRow = new TableRow( context );

            TextView labelView = new TextView( context );
            TextView valueView = new TextView( context );

            TableRow.LayoutParams params = new TableRow.LayoutParams( LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT );
            params.gravity = Gravity.RIGHT;
            labelView.setLayoutParams( params );
            labelView.setTextSize( 12 );

            params = new TableRow.LayoutParams( LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT );
            params.gravity = Gravity.LEFT;
            valueView.setLayoutParams( params );
            valueView.setPadding( 10, 0, 0, 0 );
            valueView.setTextSize( 12 );

            labelView.setText( param.getLabel() + ":" );
            valueView.setText( param.getValue() );

            tableRow.addView( labelView );
            tableRow.addView( valueView );

            layout.addView( tableRow );
        }
    }
```

On Android 4.0 and higher, this works fine. I am able to see all the rows that I expect. My problem is that on Android 2.2 and 2.3, I end up with an empty dialog box, however the size of the dialog box seems to depend on what data is actually in the object, as if all the rows are there, but set to "invisible" instead of "gone" or "visible".

Comment: This is just a shot in the dark, but try calling this method with a value of `true`: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.html#setInverseBackgroundForced(boolean)

Comment: Of course, the text is the same colour as the background! Question is, why? I have the style of the application set to "AppTheme", which, by default it is "android:Theme.Black", and for v11 onwards, it is "android:Theme.Holo". Why doesn't Theme.Black use a text colour that is visible on it's backgrounds?

Comment: Did my suggestion work?

Comment: @Ogre Quite possibly because Theme.Black is: `[a] Variant on Theme that ensures the background is completely black. This is useful for things like image viewers and media players. If you want the normal (dark background) theme do not use this, use Theme.` Taken from: [Link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.style.html#Theme_Black).

Comment: Alex, your answer didn't get the intended result, as it changed the background colour, but that highlighted what the problem was.
user2558882, thankyou, changing the theme to "android:Theme" solved the problem.